# Ubuntu 9 index files won't download

Tags: software-installation

Is the Ubuntu version 9 too old? I run Ubuntu 9 in a VM because I'm trying to use old software. Now index files fail to download. Is it impossible for that to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ubuntu 9 is no longer supported, which means that the software repositories are no longer available. It is not even possible to use the Ubuntu 9 tools to upgrade to a supported version (you would need to reinstall).